# what is the official/academic name of an area under the right-tailed standard normal curve and how to compute the quantity?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am familiar with the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

here is the formula.

$$
\varPhi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} 
\frac{e^{-u^{2}/2}} {\sqrt{2\pi}}
du
$$

there is an quantify which seems to be derived from the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

[image]

this [post](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/tables/z-table/) call it Z-Table (right) or right tail z table.
this [post](http://www.growingknowing.com/GKStatsBookNormalTable1.html) call it areas under the one-tailed standard normal curve.

what is its official/academic name in statistic or probability theory?

how to derive a formula to compute this quantity?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score 1):

the formula is

$$
\varPhi(x) - 0.5 = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x} 
\frac{e^{-u^{2}/2}} {\sqrt{2\pi}}
du\right) - 0.5 
$$

I want this name, too.

Answer (score 0):

based on @brennn

you could compute this quantity in R.

```
> pnorm(1.45) - 0.5
[1] 0.4264707
```